# Getting firebase document with it's firebaseID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I wanted to get a document by ID from an array of the documents, but couldn't find a way to get the document's ID in the first place.

I've looked everywhere for a solution, couldn't find any.

I'm posting here the solution in case anyone runs into the same trouble again.

This is what finally worked for me:

```
function getDocs(collectionName) {
    return db.collection(collectionName).get()
        .then(collection => {
            return collection.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), _id: doc.id }))
        })
}
```

Happy coding everyone

Comment: Thanks! Bookmarked for later

Comment: you should post the question and then answer your own question.